# Linux/sh: 7zip How to compressing with preserving the full path?

Tags: shell, path, sh, 7zip

I use:

```
7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

#!/bin/sh

/usr/syno/bin/7z a "/volume1/backup/backup_configfiles.7z" "/etc/firewall/" -t7z -m0=lzma2 -ms=off -mfb=64 -md=32m -mhe -mmt -mx9 -v100m -p"a"
```

In 7z file i have folder **"firewall"** only without **"etc"** folder.

How to change this to full path like **/etc/firewall/** ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

1. We need to use **p7zip** 16.02 with **-spf2** option - https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/16.02/
2. copy binaries to **/usr/bin/p7zip**
3. chmod **find "/usr/bin/p7zip/" -exec chmod 755 {} \;**

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   TIMESTAMP=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
   files

   echo "/etc/*.secrets"                   > "${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp_config_files.lst"
   echo "/etc/shadow"                      >> "${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp_config_files.lst"
   echo "/var/packages/MariaDB/etc/my.cnf" >> "${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp_config_files.lst"
   folders

   echo "/etc/firewall/"                   > "${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp_config_folders.lst"
   echo "/etc/httpd/conf/"                 >> "${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp_config_folders.lst"
   echo "/etc/mysql/"                      >> "${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp_config_folders.lst"
   Compressing...

   /usr/bin/p7zip/7za a "${BACKUP_DIR}/backup_configfiles_${TIMESTAMP}.7z" -spf2 -t7z -m0=lzma2 -ms=off -mfb=64 -md=32m -mhe -mmt -mx9 -v${SPLIT_VOLUME} -p"${PASSWORD}" -ir@"${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp_config_folders.lst" -i@"${BACKUP_DIR}/tmp_config_files.lst" -xr!thumbs.db -xr!@eaDir -xr!@tmp -xr!#recycle -xr!lost+found -xr!.DS_Store >> "$LOG_FILE2" 2>&1;
   Verifying files...

   /usr/bin/p7zip/7za t "${BACKUP_DIR}/backup_configfiles_${TIMESTAMP}.7z.001" -t7z.split -p"${PASSWORD}" >> "$LOG_FILE2" 2>&1;
   ```